# Bootstrap Menu Collapse working but isn't showing icons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I am optimizing my website for mobile devices. I noticed that my collapsible menu is working, BUT it doesn't show the icon bars. Basically, if you click in the area where the navbar icons SHOULD be, the dropdown menu will show.

How can I make the icons show so visitors can know there is a menu.

Here is my code for my menu

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#topnav">

  <div class="navbar navbar-color navbar-fixed-top" id="topnav">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">WebInsight</a>
      </div>

      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active navbutton"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li class="navbutton"><a href="services">Services</a></li>
          <li class="navbutton"><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.navbar-collapse -->

    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

The website is hustlebussellunlimited.com if you want to check out what I mean!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `navbar-default` for `navbar-inverse` to your `.navbar` div to show the toggle styles. Or write some CSS to style the `icon-bars`.

**Default Example:**

```css
.navbar.navbar-color {
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#topnav">

  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-color navbar-fixed-top" id="topnav">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">WebInsight</a>
      </div>

      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active navbutton"><a href="#home">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="navbutton"><a href="services">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li class="navbutton"><a href="contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**Custom CSS Example:**

```css
.navbar.navbar-color {
  background: cyan;
}
.navbar.navbar-color .icon-bar {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#topnav">

  <div class="navbar navbar-color navbar-fixed-top" id="topnav">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">WebInsight</a>
      </div>

      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active navbutton"><a href="#home">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="navbutton"><a href="services">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li class="navbutton"><a href="contact">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your suggestion really worked! Thank you for the help. All I needed to do was change the color of it, and add navbar-default.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked and don't forget to mark questions as answered (if they are) so others can benefit from them.

Answer (score 0):

take look and try to make adjustment to your code please note the differences in this code.

Toggle navigation
        
        
        
      
      Brand

```
<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
```