# Why isn't a button displayed on small devices using Bootstrap navbar?

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am a Bootstrap novice. On small devices, there is no button to tap for displaying the menu items. If I tap on the upper right-hand side, the menu items are shown. What am I missing?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" data-ng-app="wtApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!--        <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"> -->
        <meta name="fragment" content="!">
        <meta name="google-site-verification" content="k-yDmol0MzU1QXaTTGlhNa_gVLzUs" />
        <title>Writer's Tryst, where authors, publishers, producers, agents meet.</title>
        <meta name="description" content="A better way for writers to find publishers, producers and agents" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="Writer's Tryst, authors, publishers, producers, agents, writers, genres, manuscripts, books,   find, meet." />
        <base href="/" />
        <link  href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two:700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css.map">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize-min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-dialog.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/shares.css" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/icons/writers-tryst.png" />
    </head>
    <body data-ng-controller="mainController" >
        <script>
            (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
            (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
            })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

            ga('create', 'UA-79802711-1', 'auto');
            ga('send', 'pageview');

        </script>
        <header>
            <nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-light navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Writers-Tryst">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                        </button>
                        <div style="display: inline-block">
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="logo" src="img/writers-tryst-logo-min.png" alt="logo" /></a><br/><br/>
                            <div id="shares" class="row">   
                                <!-- Twitter -->
                                <a href="http://twitter.com/share?url=writers.tryst.ron-tornambe.com&text=<TEXT>&via=<VIA>" target="_blank" title="twitter" class="share-btn twitter">
                                    <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                                </a>

                                <!-- Facebook -->
                                <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://writers.tryst.com" target="_blank" title="facebook" class="share-btn facebook">
                                    <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                                </a>

                                <!-- StumbleUpon (url, title) 
                                <a href="http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url=http://writers.tryst.com&title=<TITLE>" target="_blank" class="share-btn stumbleupon" title="stumble-upon">
                                    <i class="fa fa-stumbleupon-circle"></i>
                                </a> -->
                                <!-- Reddit (url, title)
                                <a href="http://reddit.com/submit?url=http://writers.tryst.com&title=<TITLE>" target="_blank" class="share-btn reddit" title="reddit">
                                    <i class="fa fa-reddit-square"></i>
                                </a>  -->
                                <!-- LinkedIn -->
                                <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?url=http://writers.tryst.com&title=<TITLE>&summary=<SUMMARY>&source=<SOURCE_URL>" target="_blank" title="linked-in" class="share-btn linkedin">
                                    <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
                                </a>
                                <!-- Google Plus -->
                                <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=writers.tryst.ron-tornambe.com" target="_blank" title="google+" class="share-btn google-plus">
                                    <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div> <!--navbar-header-->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Writers-Tryst">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="active"><a id="homepage" href="#/"><i class="acctive glyphicon glyphicon-home fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#writers" id="writers-link" class="fa fa-book" > Writers</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="#enablers" id="enablers-link" class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" > Enablers</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="#about" class="fa fa-info-circle"> About</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="#privacy" class="fa fa-user-secret"> Privacy/Rules</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="#contact" class="fa fa-envelope-o"> Contact</a></li> 
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a id="login" href="#log-in"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Log-In</a></li> 
                            <li><a id="accounts-link" href="#accounts"><i class="fa fa-user hidden"></i> Create Account</a></li> 
                            <li class="dropdown" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="bottom" >
                                <button class="btn btn-custom-primary dropdown-toggle fa fa-user" style="margin-top: 8px; color: white;" data-html="true" type="button" id="user-dropdown-link" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span></button></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" data-aria-labelledby="create-account-link">
                                    <li><a id="update-profile" href="#update-profile" class="fa fa-database"> Update profile</a></li>
                                    <li><a id="manage-uploads" href="#manage-uploads" class="fa fa-book"> Manage uploads</a></li>
                                    <li><a id="review-submissions" href="#review-submissions" class="fa fa-book"> Review Submissions</a></li>
                                    <li><a id="update-submissions" href="#update-submissions" class="fa fa-book"> Update Reviews</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li ><a id="reset-pwd-link" href="#reset-pwd"></a></li> 
                        </ul>
                    </div> <!--navbar-collapse-->
                </div> <!--container fluid-->
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div>
            <div id="message" class="alert m-t-10 m-b-10"></div> 
            <div id="main" class="content container">
                <!-- angular templating -->
                <!-- this is where content will be injected -->
                <div data-ng-view></div>
            </div>
            <footer class="panel panel-default panel-transparent">
                <div id="foot1" class="text-right small">&#169; 2016 Ronald Tornambe, Inc.</div>
            </footer>
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap-dialog.js"></script>
        <script defer src="js/recaptcha.js"></script>
        <script async defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/9f2a0d923f.js"></script>
        <script defer src="js/pages.js"></script>
        <script defer src="js/common.js"></script>
        <script>
            $("#drop-toggle-1").on("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            });
            $("#accounts-link").addClass("hidden");
            $(function () {
                $("#review-submissions").on("mousedown", function () {
                    sessionStorage.setItem("submissions", "review");
                });
                $("#update-submissions").on("mousedown", function () {
                    sessionStorage.setItem("submissions", "update");
                });
                setupPage();
            });
        </script>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap Menu Collapse working but isn't showing icons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38407131/bootstrap-menu-collapse-working-but-isnt-showing-icons)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I specified navbar-light. When I changed it to navbar-default, the icon bars showed up.