# Bootstrap 4 navbar toggler not showing

Tags: bootstrap-4

This is my first attempt with Bootstrap 4 beta. I have a charity group website I made up and running in BS3 now. I am using a fixed top navbar and custom CSS. When the site is viewed smaller, not full screen, the toggle icon doesn't show up. Can you help me? I want it to be white like the nav links, and hover changes the link to read. 
This is the head links

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">    
<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="css/custombs4.css" rel="stylesheet"> `
```

the js codes are linked at the bottom of the page

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Here is my code.

```css
/* Navbar */

.navbar-custom {
    background-color: #3193de;
}


/* change the brand and text color */

.navbar-custom .navbar-brand,
.navbar-custom .navbar-text {
    text-decoration: none; color: #fff;
}


/* change the link color */

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .nav-link {
   text-decoration: none; color: #fff;
}


/* change the color of active or hovered links */

.navbar-custom .nav-item.active .nav-link,
.navbar-custom  {
  text-decoration: none;  color: #fff;
}

.nav-item .nav-link:hover {
    text-decoration: none; color: #ff0000;
}

/* for dropdown only - change the color of dropdown */

.navbar-custom .dropdown-menu {
    background-color: #3193de;
}

.navbar-custom .dropdown-item {
    text-decoration: none; color: #fff;
}

.navbar-custom .dropdown-item:hover,
.navbar-custom .dropdown-item:focus {
    text-decoration: none; color: #ff0000;
    background-color:#3193de;
}
.navbar-header .navbar-toggler {
  border: 0;
}
.navbar-toggler-icon {
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar-toggler-icon:hover {
  background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-expand-md">
      
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">AHEPA 215</a>


<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-custom" aria-controls="navbar-custom" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
      
     
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        
<ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
          
<li class="nav-item">
            
<a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          
</li>
          
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
                
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About</a>
                
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                    
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">AHEPA</a>
                    
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Chapter 215 Brothers</a>
                    
</li>          
<li class="nav-item">
            
<a class="nav-link" href="scholarship.html">Scholarships</a>
          
</li>
   
<li class="nav-item">
            
<a class="nav-link" href="photos.html">Photos</a>
          
</li>
 
<li class="nav-item">
            
<a class="nav-link" href="join.html">Join</a>
          
</li>
 
<li class="nav-item">
            
<a class="nav-link" href="calendar.html">Calendar</a>
          
</li>
 
<li class="nav-item">
            
<a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
          
</li>
      
</ul>

<ul class="navbar-nav">
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="https://www.facebook.com/portsmouth.ahepa" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
</li> 
<li class="nav-item">
<a class="nav-link" href="mailto:ahepa215@gmail.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
</li> 
</ul>       
</div>
    
</nav>
```

the page is live here http://ahepa215.org/navbar-top-fixed.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 4 Change Hamburger Toggler Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42586729/bootstrap-4-change-hamburger-toggler-color), [and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42464341/bootstrap-4-nav-doesnt-display-hamburger-on-resize/42468115)

Comment: No, I'm not using the BS svg. I read that first and nothing there helped me

Comment: `.navbar-toggler-icon` *is* the BS svg. As explained in other answers you need either `navbar-dark` or `navbar-light` to make the icon appear: http://codeply.com/go/dmGeKxPBek .. You also have the wrong `data-target` on the toggler

Answer (score 23, accepted):

@mlegg, your toggler icon isn't toggling as a result of the `id` attribute not having the same value as the `data-toggler` attribute on your `button`. The code below shows what it should be.

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>


<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
```

As for the styling of the toggle icon, you can with the following code:

```
.navbar-toggler-icon {
        background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(255,255,255, 1)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

For a thorough understanding of what's happening here, checkout @ZimSystem's answer in this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42586729/bootstrap-4-change-hamburger-toggler-color). Ultimately, you have to set the value of the stroke property in the URL of the `background-image` like so:

```
stroke='rgba(255,255,255, 1)'
```

Checkout this [codeply project](https://www.codeply.com/go/ZJkne9x87P)

Comment: You should update the answer to explain the solution was to add the SVG background image to the custom CSS