# <button> not recognized in Bootstrap4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to achieve a 'collapse icon' that's floated left followed by Copyright &copy using Bootstrap4.

I've seen other questions about this topic but none seem to actually answer the question. Other questions have different code with obvious typos, my code doesn't. Why is it that data-toggle & data-target aren't recognized when you do include all the dependencies?

```css
.titleText{
    font-size:230%;
    color:green;
    font-weight:heavy;
    letter-spacing:1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

    <nav class="navbar-nav navbar-expand-sm navbar-fixed-top text-success">
      
        <a class="navbar-brand titleText">Copyright &copy </a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseNavBar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapseNavBar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="link-nav" href="#">Map</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="link-nav" href="#">Cart</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </nav>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The button isn't showing up, just the map & cart text. If you have a workaround I would appreciate a vanilla JS solution apposed to JQuery, since I'm not that experienced with JQuery and would rather use Javascript. Button

Comment: bro button is use for burger menu, which help you want from us ?

Comment: Wow, this is almost identical: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46100302/bootstrap-4-navbar-toggler-not-showing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 4 navbar toggler not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46100302/bootstrap-4-navbar-toggler-not-showing)

Comment: @AshayMandwarya It's not the same, that person used different code so our solutions would not be the same. Just because we share similar "topic" doesn't mean we share similar "solution".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use class `text-success` in your code, so you cant see navigation bar background-color and default link color so i replace `text-sucesss` to `navbar-light bg-light`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-fixed-top navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand titleText">Copyright &copy </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseNavBar" >
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapseNavBar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Map</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Cart</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can still use `text-success` class in your code, see my answer below has it.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed the typo and updated HTML to show collapsible navBar

```css
.titleText{
    font-size:230%;
    color:green;
    font-weight:heavy;
    letter-spacing:1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light navbar-fixed-top text-success">
   <a class="navbar-brand titleText">Copyright &copy </a>

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseNavBar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapseNavBar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="link-nav" href="#">Map</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="link-nav" href="#">Cart</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</nav>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made some typo corrections, the toggle functionality now works with this code. But additional modifications are needed to align the elements correctly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" 

href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> . 
</script>

<!-- Popper JS -->

<script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
>  </script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script 
   src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"> . 
</script>

<style>    

.titleText{
    font-size:230%;
    color:green;
    font-weight:heavy;
    letter-spacing:1px;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top text-success">

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
 data-target="#collapseNavBar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">Menu</span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapseNavBar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="link-nav" href="#">Map</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="link-nav" href="#">Cart</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <a class="navbar-brand titleText">Copyright &copy </a>
    </nav>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I will construct the complete aligned html if need be. Hope this helps!

Comment: Aravindh, Can u point out my mistakes, I cant seem to find them or explain why it didn't render properly

Comment: <div="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapseNavBar"> should be <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapseNavBar">

Comment: </style> tag was missing.

Comment: Glad to know !But It was my bad not to write the aligned html which I believe should be easier for you now after these corrections!